# How to Change Header Title Component in React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am Using Product Search Component In Header Of EmptyPage , It works Fine . Now My Req is to change the Header Title Component Dynamically , If i come From DiagnosticSearch Page I need The Header Title Component Should Be  , How to change it Dynamically???

```
      <Stack.Screen name='EmptyPage' component={EmptyPage} options={{ headerShown:true,headerTitle: () => <ProductSearch/>}}/>
```

Comment: can you share an expo snack where i can check?

Comment: Sorry ,I can't . Just wanna Know How to Change Header Title Component Dynamically According To The Page I am Coming From

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the EmptyPage screen component,
create:

```
export const screenOptions = navData => {
  const title = navData.route ? navData.route.params : null
  return {
    headerTitle: title,
}
```

and inside the function of EmptyPage

```
useEffect(() => {

      props.navigation.setParams({ title:theUpdatedTitle })
   
  }, [theUpdatedTitle])
```

now in the navigation :

```
<Stack.Screen name='EmptyPage' component={EmptyPage} options{importedScreenOptions}/>
```

hope this helps you